# How to horizontally and vertically center a single item, but allow other items to wrap around it

Tags: html, css, flexbox

The layout I'm trying to achieve:

[image]
[image]

The concept is to have an element that is always centered within a container and then another element that is stuck to the side of it. If this side element is too wide, it should wrap below the main element without disturbing the centering.

```css
#container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: grey;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
}

#container::before {
  content: '';
  flex: 1;
}

#mainText {
  font-size: 60px;
}

#subText {
  flex: 1;
  font-size: 16px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <span id="mainText">MAIN</span>
  <span id="subText">sub</span>
</div>
```

This snippet is where I've started, but there's a bunch of issues that I'm still scratching my head on how to approach. For one, the sub text element will not wrap correctly, and even if it did I'm certain that the vertical/horizontal centering would be broken. Also, I'm not sure how to make sure the baselines of the two text elements are the same. Perhaps flexbox is not the right approach for this layout? To be clear, **this layout should work for any container size**. Hardcoding positions would be unacceptable.

Comment: `flex: 1` on the pseudo-element won't help because the `flex-grow: 1` component simply consumes free space. So when the sub text grows too long, the pseudo will just shrink. The key is to find something that freezes the left side at the same length as the right side, which would keep the middle item centered and force the sub text to wrap. Without fixed lengths, I don't believe flex, grid or anything in CSS provides that functionality. And after wrapping, the left side would need to "unfreeze" to allow for centering again.

Comment: Of course, the simplest approach is to keep the subtext on the second line at all times. Another approach would be to keep the heading and subtext in the same element, allowing for the entire line to remain centered (but the subtext may break across both lines). Just throwing this out there. I get that neither may be possible in your case.

Comment: Are you looking for a Javascript free solution?

Answer (score 2):

you can use `display: table-cell;`

```css
#container {
   width: 400px;
   height: 200px;
   background-color: grey;
   color: white;
   min-height: 10em;
   display: table-cell;
   vertical-align: middle;
   text-align:center;
}
#mainText {
  font-size: 60px;
}

#subText {
  flex: 1;
  font-size: 16px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <span id="mainText">MAIN</span>
  <span id="subText">sub</span>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question being asked. The OP is looking for text that is *fixed* in the center with secondary text that wraps around it. This just centers the *combined* two texts by using `text-align: center;`, which is not the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an *approximation* where the only requirement is to know the width of the main title and you will not have the sub element centered on wrapping.

```css
#container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(red, red) center/100% 1px no-repeat, 
    linear-gradient(red, red) center/1px 100% no-repeat;
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
  margin: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#container>div {
  width: 100%;
  font-size:0;
}

#mainText {
  font-size: 60px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(50% + 160px/2); /* 160px is the width */
  text-align: right;
}

#subText {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>
    <div id="mainText"><span>MAIN</span></div>
    <span id="subText">sub text</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="container">
  <div>
    <div id="mainText"><span>MAIN</span></div>
    <span id="subText">sub very long long text</span>
  </div>
</div>
```